# during an interview vs. at an interview?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

I am always baffled by the choices of prepositions. When I write something like

> We should focus our learning on what questions are asked during an interview/at an interview

I wonder should I use "during" or "at"? and should I use plural as in "interviews" or just singular?

And are there any other better ways to say this?

Comment: Both seem fine - I think "at" would be more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give "during" a very slight preference but either "during" or "at" are otherwise fine.

I don't particularly care for the "our learning" in the original and might word the original thought as "We should focus on studying the topics likely to come up during an interview.". An additional alternative to either "during" or "at" is "as part of".